# Grails GORM mapping contraints for varchar columns

Tags: database, grails, grails-orm

I'm reviewing codes made by previous employees that served the same project as mine. While I'm reviewing their code, I encountered many `Domain` class constraints similar to this:

```
String title
String notes

static mapping = {
    .....
    title column: 'title'
    notes column: 'notes'
    .....
}

static constraints = {
    .....
    title nullable: false, size: 1..50, blank: true
    notes nullable: true, size: 0..500, blank: true
    .....
}
```

I get the point that `null` values and empty strings are different, hence the `nullable` and `blank` constraints. But should you really specify `0` as the minimum length of `nullable` columns and specify `1` to those `non-nullable` columns?

If it is indeed, then what would be the difference to those `Domains` that doesn't use similar constraints? Before reading their codes, I've already coded many `Domain` classes just using *only* the `nullable` constraint, and they're working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is redundancy on the constraints.

I would have refactored it to something like this:

```
static constraints = {
    .....
    title nullable: false, max:50
    notes nullable: true, max:500
    .....
}
```

Comment: How about the `blank` constraint? Should one not use the `blank` constraint when  a `nullable` constraint is set to `true`?

Comment: no, blank:true basically means length zero is allowed blank:false means length zero is not allowed